# How do you add a background image to and activity and align it to the bottom right?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity, I'll call it mainactivity for now. And I want to know how to put a background onto it. I know how to add the background by adding `android:background="@drawables/background"`

But I want to align it to the bottom right (Gravity) and keeps it's original ratio because the background tag is stretching it

This is what I have got so far. A styles.xml file and the background tag on the linear layout set to @style/Background

Styles file:

```
        <style name="Background">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background" 
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
/>
    </style>
```

What do I add/change (or anything else I could do) to make the drawable 'lock' to the bottom right corner?

Thanks

Comment: Your `style` element is plain wrong. You can't have views there, only attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new *bitmap drawable* that specifies a *source drawable* and a *gravity*, then use that drawable as background.

For instance, create a new *bitmap drawable* named `aligned_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

and then set your background to `@drawable/aligned_background`.

Comment: Do you also know how to scale the image, so it's a thumbnail in the corner?

Comment: @user1195777: I guess you could wrap it in a _scale drawable_?

Comment: Is it possible to use another drawable xml in `android:src` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone how views this.
With the help of the fist answer on this page. I got a file that works for me.
I have a drawable bitmap XML file. And then the Linear layout on main.xml has its background tag set to "@drawable/aligned background"

The file (aligned_background) that is exactly what I wanted is as follows:
It's fine now!
I got it.
This is my final bitmap drawable that works great for me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@drawable/background" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention, I added the scaleType tag so it would fit nicely in the bottom left corner of the screen.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it would only be on the left for users with LTR locales. For Right-to-Left locales, the starting point is on the right.